# When does Master Chief get captured as seen in the Scanned trailer?

Tags: halo-4

The [Scanned trailer for Halo 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GO376G4tbGM) shows the Chief captured by the Prometheans and being scanned by one of the Promethean Knights. When does this take place? Is it a trailer for Halo 5 since this doesn't actually happen in Halo 4?

Comment: Have you finished the currently available story without encountering that scene? If so, then there's no way we know more than you do about when that happens. I suspect it simply doesn't happen, like the scene with Chief flying out of Forward Unto Dawn with a jetpack.

Comment: It simply doesn't happen? So they trailers are "just for fun" and have little (if any) correlation to the story? Didn't Kiki and the others say they are designing all the Halo 4-related media to tell a single story and to link up or something like that?

Comment: As I said, if you don't know then we don't know. Any answer would be speculation or opinion, which is why I voted to close this question.

Comment: For Halo 3 there was a [battlefield vignette trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjhSp7xGsMc) that ends with a broken Master Chief held aloft by a Brute. The battle doesn't even happen in the game. I think they have a _lot_ of artistic license.

Comment: I say we keep the question open. Maybe it'll happen later on as the storyline unfolds so we can update this question then. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Your comment about all Halo 4-related media being designed to "tell a single story and to link up" makes me think that the RELATED MEDIA tells a coherent story. The game is, itself, not Halo 4-related media - it IS Halo 4.

Comment: Usually, it's just a demo to showcase the newer elements in the game, rather than being a part of the storyline.  I played through Halo 4 as well, no mention of that part either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed single player on Heroic last night, and the scene in question does not take place.  A few similar scenes do take place:

> Didact does hold the Chief aloft(with the Force I guess) a few times with his arms held out.  Once when you first release him and again at the climax of the story.  There are no flash backs to the Chief childhood.  A Promethean Kight also does the 'jump on you head split open scream thing' when you first encounter them on requiem.